# HTML form validation pattern showing error

Tags: javascript, html

HTML pattern form showing to match correct request format

What I have to do is make a pattern for a phone number text input
[here is what I have to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA6aI.png)

This is what i've tried and I keep getting [this error on my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2nYd.png)

`<input type="text" name="phoneNum" size="20" title="(+971)NNNNNNNNNN" value="(+971)05" pattern="^[0-9]{8}$" required>`

I tried adding `pattern="^\(+971)05\[0-9]{8}$"`but it would make the field not required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<input type="text" name="phoneNum" size="20" title="(+971)NNNNNNNNNN" pattern="^\(\+971\)\d{10}$" required>
```

- ^ and $ denote the start and end of the input string.
- ( and ) escape the parentheses in the pattern
- + matches the plus symbol
- \d{10} matches any digit (\d) exactly 10 times.